# Details on Current Salesforce Setup

Tags: lightning, lightning-sync-configurations

We recently had the person who handled our Salesforce setup and configuration leave the business and the salesforce management has now been passed on to new hands. Our previous setup was not well documented at all and being new to this type of role we would like to get a handle on what's been set up and how...

I was wondering if there was a way to get a system map or configurations map of the current salesforce setup. Like what integrations there are, what workflows are setup up etc.. So far we have been going through the configuration manually to try and map that out, just wondering if there was a different way to achieve the same goal?

Hopefully less manual?